# I was wondering how to make a cell go to another view controller in Xcode 9, swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I've been trying to figure out how to configure a cell to go to another view, in this case, I'm listing a group of services after login and when the user taps on a service they like, it takes them to a map. But I don't know how to set the cell up in a way that it takes them to the map when its tapped. I've tried creating a segue but nothing happens when the cell is tapped. I'm new to programming and was wondering if someone could explain this.

I've watched a bunch of youtube videos which gave me the understanding on how to set up the cell (basic stuff).

Would really appreciate some advice, thanks!

Hope this post helps anyone that's dipping their feet into the programming journey!

Thank you, happy coding!

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import UIKit
struct cellData {
let cell : Int!
let text : String!
let image : UIImage! }

class ListServicesTVC: UITableViewController {

var arrayOfCellData = [cellData]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    arrayOfCellData = [cellData(cell : 1, text : "Barber Services", image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "barberservice") ),
                       cellData(cell : 2, text : "Salon Services", image : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "salonservice"))]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayOfCellData.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 1 {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BarberServiceCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! BarberServiceCell

        cell.barberImageView.image = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.barberServicesLabel.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell
    }
    else if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 2 {

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SalonServicesCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! SalonServicesCell

        cell.salonImageView.image = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.salonServicesLabel.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell
    }

    else {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BarberServiceCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! BarberServiceCell

        cell.barberImageView.image = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.barberServicesLabel.text = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].text

        return cell
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 1 {
        return 120
    }
    else if arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row].cell == 2 {
        return 120
    }
    else {
        return 120
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Do not write let `cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BarberServiceCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! BarberServiceCell`. That's avoid the `reuse` of cells. Use instead `tableView.dequeueCell...` For detecting the tap, you need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelect:`

Comment: Don't make the *cell* (the view) go to another view, make the *data source item* (the model) go to another view

Comment: how would the full line code look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the steps below:

- create A tableView Outlet in ViewController Class.
- create a TableViewCell Class and register with tableView Outlet.
- then, create a DetailViewController Class ( i.e, When You click on a particular cell, it should show details of that particular cell)

In main "ViewController" do the following code

`class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {`'

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


var tableData: [String] = ["Apple", "Samsung", "LG"]

// 1 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


// Register customCell with tableView Outlet
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}

// 2
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

// 3 
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    let cell: CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    // injecting data to cell
    cell.lblCompanyName.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.imgCompanyName.image = UIImage(named: tableData[indexPath.row])

    return cell

}

// 4
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    let detailObj=DetailViewController(nibName: "DetailViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailObj, animated: true)
    detailObj.nameVar=tableData[indexPath.row]
    detailObj.imgStr=tableData[indexPath.row]

}
```

2. In "CustomTableViewCell" class

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var imgCompanyName: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var lblCompanyName: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}}
```

3. in "DetailViewController"

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
     var nameVar:String?
     var imgStr:String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        name.text=nameVar
        image.image=UIImage(named: imgStr!)

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}}
```

**End of the Code**

I think I am clear, if you have any quires just comment below.

Answer (score -1):

Hi try the following set of code, I have added few additional changes in your code which is necessary for passing the details, I hope it will solve your issue.
I have added only the extra codes which you needed

```
class ListServicesTVC: UITableViewController {

// Add this variable in this class and use it whereever you needed it in this class
var selectedItem: cellData?


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Now maintain the selected data in the local variable we declared
    selectedItem = arrayOfCellData[indexPath.row]

    // Now perform the segue operation
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "VIEW_CONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER_OF_MAP_CLASS", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "VIEW_CONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER_OF_MAP_CLASS" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? VIEW_CONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER_OF_MAP_CLASS
        destinationVC?.selectedItem = self.selectedItem // Pass the selected item here which we have saved on didSelectRotAt indexPath delegate
    }
}
```

In Second class:

```
class VIEW_CONTROLLER_IDENTIFIER_OF_MAP_CLASS: UIViewController {


// Add this variable in this class and use it whereever you needed it in this class
var selectedItem: cellData?
```